# How can i generate a curve arrow tube?

Tags: graphics3d

Following the document, I generate a curve arrow tube using following code:

```
arrowtube = 
 With[{ra = .1, arhd = .25}, 
  Graphics3D[{Arrowheads[arhd], 
    Arrow[Tube[
      BSplineCurve[Table[{Cos[t], Sin[t], 0}, {t, 0, 3 Pi/2, Pi/10}]],
       ra]]}, Boxed -> False, ViewPoint -> {1, 1, 1}, 
   ImageSize -> {100, Automatic}, Method -> {"ShrinkWrap" -> True}]]
```

and it gives me

[image: curve arrow tube]

It seems that the arrow doesn't align with the curved path. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The problem is that with the default cone, the pivot is not in the center, which can lead to the disconnected appearance. One solution is to specify a custom arrow tip to have more control over the pivot (which in this case is one fourth of the way from the base of the cone, where its center of mass is located):

```
arrowtube = With[
  {ra = .1, arhd = .25, 
   arrowtip = Graphics3D@Cone[{{-1/4, 0, 0}, {3/4, 0, 0}}, 0.3]},
  Graphics3D[
    {Arrowheads[{{arhd, 1, arrowtip}}], 
     Arrow[Tube[BSplineCurve[Table[{Cos[t], Sin[t], 0}, {t, 0, 3 Pi/2, Pi/10}]], ra]]},
     Boxed -> False, ViewPoint -> {1, 1, 1}, ImageSize -> {300, Automatic},
     Method -> {"ShrinkWrap" -> True}
  ]
]
```

[image: Custom arrow tip]

To get a better idea, here's a look inside:
`arrowtip = Graphics3D[{Opacity[0.5], Cone[{{-1/4, 0, 0}, {3/4, 0, 0}}, 0.3]}]`

[image: Custom arrow tip inside]